# How to fix disordered column and send them to csv file

Tags: bash

I have a text file containing 4 columns like the following shape

```
17  3.852734   -0.678193  -0.035636

17  -3.852814  -0.677994  -0.035671

7   -0.000016  0.555172   0.055132

6   1.221054   -0.054820  -0.450556

6   -1.221077  -0.054796  -0.450652
```

I am intended to convert it to the following shape

```
17                 3.852734   -0.678193   -0.035636

17                -3.852814   -0.677994   -0.035671

7                 -0.000016    0.555172    0.055132

6                  1.221054   -0.054820   -0.450556

6                 -1.221077   -0.054796   -0.450652
```

When I use the bellow code, I cannot reach the target format

```
column -t file.txt
```

Is there any other straightway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to respect this exact spacing, you could use

```
awk '{printf("%-15s%12.6f%12.6f%12.6f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}' file.txt
```

It looks like you have empty lines. I don’t know if it is a mistake when copy/pasting here or if the input file really has them, in which case you may handle them like this:

```
awk '{if ($0=="") print; else printf("%-15s%12.6f%12.6f%12.6f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}' file.txt
```